# regular expression POSIX problem on postgresql

Tags: regex, postgresql, posix-ere

I want to delete all 2 letter words in a string with several words.

I came up with this solution :

```
SELECT regexp_replace('UN DE DA ','\s{1}[A-Z]{2}\s{1}',' ','g');

SELECT regexp_replace('UN DE DA ','^[A-Z]{2}\s{1}',' ','g');

SELECT regexp_replace('UN DE DA','[A-Z]{2}$',' ','g');
```

BUT i would like to have on one regexp_replace instead of three
I tested this

```
SELECT regexp_replace('UN DE DA ','\s{1}[A-Z]{2}\s{1}|^[A-Z]{2}\s{1}|[A-Z]{2}$',' ','g');
```

but it doesn't work => i still have DE

Your sincerely
Loïc

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you actually want to remove the two letter words, then it seems that your replacement should be empty string, not a single space.  We can try matching on the pattern:

```
\y[A-Z]{2}\y
```

This will match any two uppercase letters surrounded by word boundaries, which include spaces, or the start/end of the string.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('UN DE DA ', '\y[A-Z]{2}\y', '', 'g');
```

### Demo

The above query returns three spaces, which are left behind from the original string.